# Why is this pascal triangle function not giving a list index error?

Tags: python

I've been doing an assignment for uni that requires us to generate Pascal triangles in python. My code works but I don't understand why as I was expecting to get a List Index error for line 8 (and the ones after too).

Here is the function itself, it would be great if someone could explain what happens.

```
def generate_pascal(n):
    pascal = []

    for i in range(n + 1):  # columns
        row = []
        row.append(1)  # first item is always 1
        for j in range(i):  # rows
            # The pascal list is empty shouldn't I be getting an index error?
            last = len(pascal) - 1
            row.append(pascal[last][j + 1] + pascal[last][j])
        row.append(0)  # To be able to add the last item to its adjacent number
        pascal.append(row)

    return pascal
```

Comment: hint : you could have used python's step debugger (https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to trace the function's execution.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I had no idea python had such a debugger, I've been relying on tracebacks all this time. This is crazy useful, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first iteration, `i` is equal to `0`. `range(0)` is empty, so that `for` loop doesn't run, and your `pascal` list is immediately appended to without running the `for` loop in `j`.

Comment: I had no idea range wouldn't run with 0. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MaxMonteil it's not that `range(0)` "wouldn't run", but that it returns either an empty list (Python 2.x) or an empty generator (Python 3.x), so the `for` loop exits immediatly.